# Blazor wasm to public APIs

Tags: api, blazor

I have a Blazor wasm project (.NET6) that uses internal APIs to communicate with the client application. The project uses IdentityServer4 to authenticate users and most APIs require authorization before being granted access.

My question is how can I move those internal APIs to public APIs? What changes do I need to make in the authentication system so APIs can be accessed? How should I move the APIs to being public? Do I need to create separate API users as opposed to app users right now?

Comment: I don't have public APIs. The internal APIs are within the Blazor server project. The Client calls these APIs using HttpClient. So for example, the starter Blazor wasm project also has APIs on the server side which are called by the client. If one was to move the WeatherForecast API to the public, how would that be done?

Answer (score 0):

1. Add access tokens to the requests being sent from your Blazor wasm app. It's fairly involved, but here's a good [resource](https://code-maze.com/using-access-token-with-blazor-webassembly-httpclient/).
2. Configure the API to accept access tokens ([from this guide](https://code-maze.com/identityserver4-ui-webapi-basic-security/)).

   public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
   {
   app.UseStaticFiles();
   app.UseRouting();

   app.UseIdentityServer();

   app.UseAuthorization();

   app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
   {
   endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
   });

}

Comment: Thanks for pointing in this direction. Let me try that out.